# Appending numpy arrays into two binary files

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want to create two binary files to **append** numpy arrays into each one of them during a loop. I wrote the following method (I use Python 2.7):

```
for _ in range(5):
    C = np.random.rand(1, 5)
    r = np.random.rand(1, 5)
    with open("C.bin", "ab") as file1, open("r.bin", "ab") as file2:
        # Append to binary files
        np.array(C).tofile(file1)
        np.array(r).tofile(file2)

# Now printing to check if appending is successful
C = np.load("C.bin")
r = np.load("r.bin")
print (C)
print (r)
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 15, in <module>
    C = np.load("C.bin")
  File "/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 429, in load
    "Failed to interpret file %s as a pickle" % repr(file))
IOError: Failed to interpret file 'C.bin' as a pickle
```

I tried to fix it but I cannot see anything more. Any help is appreciated.

NOTE: I intentionally want to use `np.load` because later on I will be loading the dataset from the disk into a numpy array for further processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `save` method that is built in the numpy to store the array in the files. Here what your code should look like:

```
for _ in range(5):
    C = np.random.rand(1, 5)
    r = np.random.rand(1, 5)

    np.save('C', C)
    np.save('r', r)

    # Now printing to check if appending is successful
    C = np.load("C.npy")
    r = np.load("r.npy")
    print (C)
    print (r)
    del C, r
```

Please refer to the documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.load.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this is not appending, rather rewriting! I printed it outside the loop and it looks like it is only saving the last block

Comment: Hmmm I got your point @Medo , you can create an array of arrays and store it as one. Or you can use `np.savez()` function that allow you to store more than one item in the same file, please check the sintax at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.load.html

Comment: Good hint. Thanks alot